# How to implement a for loop to iterate over this dataset

Tags: python, loops

I'm implementing the following code to get match history data from an API:

```
my_matches = watcher.match.matchlist_by_puuid(
        region=my_region, 
        puuid=me["puuid"], 
        count=100,
        start=1)
```

The max items I can display per page is 100 (count), I would like my_matches to equal the first 1000 matches, thus looping start from 1 - 10.

Is there any way to effectively do this?

Comment: how does `my_matches` look? What does `watcher.match.matchlist_by_puuid...` return?

Comment: It returns the following (shortened):

['EUW1_6062024675', 'EUW1_6062003040', 'EUW1_6061900155', 'EUW1_6061935516', 'EUW1_6061923994', 'EUW1_6061842057', 'EUW1_6061801871', 'EUW1_6060921295', 'EUW1_6060887772', 'EUW1_6060558898', 'EUW1_6060597127', 'EUW1_6059954213', 'EUW1_6059914633', ...]

Comment: Please check if my answer below works. I am currently not able to run the code snippet myself.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/riot-watcher/downloads/pdf/latest/) (see page 17), this function returns a list of strings. The function can only return a 100 `count` max. Also, it accepts a `start` for where to start returning these matches (which defaults at 0). A possible solution for your problem would look like this:

```
allMatches = [] # will become a list containing 10 lists of matches
for match_page in range(9): # remember arrays start at 0!
    countNum = match_page * 100 # first will be 0, second 100, third 200 etc...
    my_matches = watcher.match.matchlist_by_puuid(
    region=my_region, 
    puuid=me["puuid"], 
    count=100,
    start=countNum)
    # ^ Notice how we use countNum as the start for returning
    allMatches.append(my_matches)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remain concise, and you want your `matches`to be a 1000 long list of results, you can concatenate direclty all the outputs of size 100 as:

```
import itertools
matches = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(watcher.match.matchlist_by_puuid(
        region=my_region, 
        puuid=me["puuid"], 
        count=100,
        start=i*100) for i in range(10)))
```